# Trying to get rid of a data frame row

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to get rid of a data frame row. I read the data with

```
temp_data <- read.table(blablabla)
```

and then when I try to get rid of the first row with

```
temp_data <- temp_data[-1,]
```

it turns `temp_data` into a vector. Why is this happening?

Comment: Firstly, are u using `header=T`? Secondly have you tried `temp_data<-data.frame(temp_data[-1,])`

Comment: It is likely that there is only one column in the data.  Try `temp_data[-1, , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: -Richard Scriven , yes! it is actually, so I guess i know what the problem is now. thanks!  MaxPD , another fix, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by others, by default for `[`, it is `drop=TRUE`.  From the `?"["`

> drop:   For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the
>   lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for
>   extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further
>   details.

So, we need

```
 temp_data[-1, , drop=FALSE]
```

If we convert to `data.table`, for subsetting the rows, it is not needed,

```
 library(data.table)
 temp_data[-1]
```

#### data

```
 temp_data <- data.frame(Col1 = 1:5)
```